# Why does my texture not apply? (Direct3D, mode XYZRHW)

Tags: c++, directx, textures, 2d, direct3d

I am working on a 2D game and I can't seem to be able to add a texture to my quad. I have precisely followed some tutorials and it seemed quite simple, but all I got was a quad of its default color (white). Texture size is 64x64, which are multiples of 2, so that shouldn't be a problem. Here is my code:

```
#include "includes.h"
#define CUSTOMFVF (D3DFVF_XYZRHW | D3DFVF_DIFFUSE | D3DFVF_TEX1)

LPDIRECT3D9 d3d;
LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 d3ddev;
LPDIRECT3DVERTEXBUFFER9 v_buffer;
LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9 Tex = NULL;

struct SQR
{
    float TLX = tile * 2;
    float TLY = tile * 4;
    float width = tile * 8;
    float height = tile * 6;
} sqr;

struct D3DVERTEX
{
    float fX,
    fY,
    fZ,
    fRHW;
    D3DCOLOR colour;
    float fU,
    fV;
} vertex[4];

void GenerateQuad()
{
    vertex[0] = { sqr.TLX - 0.5f, sqr.TLY - 0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0xffffffff, 0.0f, 0.0f };
    vertex[1] = { sqr.TLX + sqr.width - 0.5f, sqr.TLY - 0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0xffffffff, 1.0f, 0.0f };
    vertex[3] = { sqr.TLX - 0.5f, sqr.TLY + sqr.height - 0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0xffffffff, 0.0f, 1.0f };
    vertex[2] = { sqr.TLX + sqr.width - 0.5f, sqr.TLY + sqr.height - 0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0xffffffff, 1.0f, 1.0f };
}

IDirect3DTexture9 *LoadTexture(LPCWSTR fileName)
{
    IDirect3DTexture9 *d3dTexture;
    D3DXIMAGE_INFO SrcInfo;

    D3DCOLOR colorkey = 0xffffffff;


    if (FAILED(D3DXCreateTextureFromFileEx(d3ddev, fileName, 0, 0, 1, 0,
        D3DFMT_A8R8G8B8, D3DPOOL_MANAGED, D3DX_FILTER_NONE, D3DX_DEFAULT,
        colorkey, &SrcInfo, NULL, &d3dTexture)))
    {
        return NULL;
    }


    return d3dTexture;
}

bool Init3D()
{

    d3d = Direct3DCreate9(D3D_SDK_VERSION);

    D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS d3dpp;

    ZeroMemory(&d3dpp, sizeof(d3dpp));
    d3dpp.Windowed = TRUE;
    d3dpp.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;
    d3dpp.hDeviceWindow = hwnd;
    d3dpp.BackBufferFormat = D3DFMT_X8R8G8B8;
    d3dpp.BackBufferWidth = 960;
    d3dpp.BackBufferHeight = 600;


    d3d->CreateDevice(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT,
        D3DDEVTYPE_HAL,
        hwnd,
        D3DCREATE_MIXED_VERTEXPROCESSING,
        &d3dpp,
        &d3ddev);

    GenerateQuad();
    v_buffer = NULL;

    d3ddev->CreateVertexBuffer(4 * sizeof(D3DVERTEX),
        0,
        CUSTOMFVF,
        D3DPOOL_MANAGED,
        &v_buffer,
        NULL);

    d3ddev->SetStreamSource(0, v_buffer, 0, sizeof(D3DVERTEX));



    d3ddev->SetRenderState(D3DRS_LIGHTING, FALSE);
    d3ddev->SetRenderState(D3DRS_ALPHABLENDENABLE, TRUE);
    d3ddev->SetRenderState(D3DRS_SRCBLEND, D3DBLEND_SRCALPHA);
    d3ddev->SetRenderState(D3DRS_DESTBLEND, D3DBLEND_INVSRCALPHA);
    d3ddev->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_ALPHAOP, D3DTOP_MODULATE);



    Tex=LoadTexture(L"Tex.bmp");

    v_buffer->Lock(0, 0, (void**)&pVoid, 0);
    memcpy(pVoid, vertex, sizeof(vertex));
    v_buffer->Unlock();

    d3ddev->DrawPrimitive(D3DPT_TRIANGLEFAN, 0, 2);

    d3ddev->SetTexture(0, Tex);

    return TRUE;
}

DWORD renderf()
{
    d3ddev->Clear(0, NULL, D3DCLEAR_TARGET, D3DCOLOR_ARGB(0xff, 0, 0, 0), 1.0f, 0);

    sqr.TLX += 1.0f;
    GenerateQuad();



    v_buffer->Lock(0, sizeof(vertex), (void**)&pVoid, D3DLOCK_NO_DIRTY_UPDATE);
    memcpy(pVoid, vertex, sizeof(vertex));
    v_buffer->Unlock();

    d3ddev->SetTexture(0, Tex);


    d3ddev->BeginScene();

    d3ddev->SetFVF(CUSTOMFVF);




    d3ddev->SetStreamSource(0, v_buffer, 0, sizeof(D3DVERTEX));


    d3ddev->DrawPrimitive(D3DPT_TRIANGLEFAN, 0, 2);

    d3ddev->EndScene();


    d3ddev->Present(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    return 0x0000;
}
```

Comment: Did you check that Tex != NULL?  There could have been an error loading the image file.

Comment: Yes, that appears to be the problem. While debugging the file, Visual Studio Ultimate doesn't search in the EXE directory but the project directory. Thank you so much, I would never have noticed it myself.

Comment: I posted it as an answer so we can mark it resolved :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After loading Textures, check that the texture is not equal to NULL.  You should also check that your d3ddevice object and other allocated resources are not NULL, because if it fails to allocate and you don't check, you won't know it until you're scratching your head wondering why something isn't rendering.